# "Could not prepare statement" OneToMany

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-repositories

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

> Write a web service that gives the details of a repository: id, name, user name and
> list of commits.

It needs to be returned as a `JSON` format, for example :

```json
{
  "repository_id": "1",
  "repository_name": "My repo",
  "owner": "Noah",
  "commits": [
    "First commit",
    "Second commit",
    "Third commit"
  ]
}
```

You will find the database structure below :
[image: Database structure]

Here is my `CrudRepository` with the query I am trying to build:

```java
public interface RepositoriesDB extends CrudRepository<Repository, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT r.repositoryId, r.repositoryName, r.owner.userName, r.commits FROM Repository r WHERE r.repositoryId = :repoId")
    List<Object[]> getRepo(@Param("repoId") long repoId);
}
```

My `User` class :

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String userLogin;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Repository> repositories;
}
```

My `Repository` class :

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Repository {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long repositoryId;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25)
    private String repositoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "repository", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Commit> commits;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_login", nullable = false)
    private User owner;
}
```

My `Commit` class :

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Commit {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long commitId;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "repository_id", nullable = false)
    private Repository repository;
}
```

And finally, here is the stacktrace :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not prepare statement; SQL [select repository0_.repository_id as col_0_0_, repository0_.repository_name as col_1_0_, user1_.user_name as col_2_0_, . as col_3_0_, commits2_.commit_id as commit_i1_0_, commits2_.date as date2_0_, commits2_.message as message3_0_, commits2_.repository_id as reposito4_0_ from repository repository0_ cross join user user1_ inner join commit commits2_ on repository0_.repository_id=commits2_.repository_id where repository0_.owner_login=user1_.user_login and repository0_.repository_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select repository0_.repository_id as col_0_0_, repository0_.repository_name as col_1_0_, user1_.user_name as col_2_0_, . as col_3_0_, commits2_.commit_id as commit_i1_0_, commits2_.date as date2_0_, commits2_.message as message3_0_, commits2_.repository_id as reposito4_0_ from repository repository0_ cross join user user1_ inner join commit commits2_ on repository0_.repository_id=commits2_.repository_id where repository0_.owner_login=user1_.user_login and repository0_.repository_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
[...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
[...]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT REPOSITORY0_.REPOSITORY_ID AS COL_0_0_, REPOSITORY0_.REPOSITORY_NAME AS COL_1_0_, USER1_.USER_NAME AS COL_2_0_, .[*] AS COL_3_0_, COMMITS2_.COMMIT_ID AS COMMIT_I1_0_, COMMITS2_.DATE AS DATE2_0_, COMMITS2_.MESSAGE AS MESSAGE3_0_, COMMITS2_.REPOSITORY_ID AS REPOSITO4_0_ FROM REPOSITORY REPOSITORY0_ CROSS JOIN USER USER1_ INNER JOIN COMMIT COMMITS2_ ON REPOSITORY0_.REPOSITORY_ID=COMMITS2_.REPOSITORY_ID WHERE REPOSITORY0_.OWNER_LOGIN=USER1_.USER_LOGIN AND REPOSITORY0_.REPOSITORY_ID=?"; expected "*, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, UNIQUE"; SQL statement:
select repository0_.repository_id as col_0_0_, repository0_.repository_name as col_1_0_, user1_.user_name as col_2_0_, . as col_3_0_, commits2_.commit_id as commit_i1_0_, commits2_.date as date2_0_, commits2_.message as message3_0_, commits2_.repository_id as reposito4_0_ from repository repository0_ cross join user user1_ inner join commit commits2_ on repository0_.repository_id=commits2_.repository_id where repository0_.owner_login=user1_.user_login and repository0_.repository_id=? [42001-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1053)
[...]
```

I believe the problem comes from the fact that I'm trying to select a `OneToMany` relation, since I don't have this issue when selecting the owner because I have an `@JsonIgnore` annotation and infinite loops...
Except, in this case, I NEED to select the list of transaction :(

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE r.repositoryId = ?1` instead of `WHERE r.repositoryId = :repoId` ?

Comment: yup I already have :/ doesn't work either

Comment: Missing comma between r.owner.userName and r.commits?

Comment: @Alien just a typo when I copy / pasted, my bad. I had the comma in my code so not the problem either :/

Comment: I think your have to change `public interface RepositoriesDB extends CrudRepository<Repository, Long>` since `Repository` have a `Long` id type and not `String` one

Comment: Yup that's my bad 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your sql query is the `r.commits` part. It is a list of values and sql column accept only a `single (or scalar)` value type like `number`, `varchar` etc

Since the relation between `Repository` and `Commit` entities is`One-To-Many` association so `r.commits` is a list of values so Hibernate fails to prepare the sql statement.

You can remove the r.commits part from your sql query and it will works.

If you would like to get the list of commits for your repository, you can implement a specefic method for that.
Something like

```
public interface CommitRepository extends JpaRepository<Commit, Long> {
      List<Commit> findAllByRepository(Repository repository);
}
```

you can pass to this method the `repository` object that you want to get all the associated commits.

Also, since the `Repository.repositoryId` is `Long` data type so you have to change the `RepositoriesDB` defenition to

```
public interface RepositoriesDB extends JpaRepository<Repository, Long>
```